# arraylist size less than real

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, webdriver

I was using webdriver to grab web elements with class name `topredo` into ArrayList.

Seeing that the web elements is increasing when screen scrolls, i use `while` loop to do scroll and grab.

Java code like this:

```
outer: while (isContinue) {    
        List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.className("torpedo"));
        /* do screen scrolling*/
}
```

It runs well until the last loop.

In last secode loop, i get the `all.size()` result 208, but in the last loop, the `all.size()` result is 172 while the real total size of web elements on browser is 243,and i use eclipse debug to see the list stack content.

Screenshots like this:

- all.size()

[image: all.size()]

- content end on index 171

[image: content end on index 171]

So my question is why `all.size()` less than `the real size`, and why the contents on index greater than 171 are unvisiable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Provide more information: 1. What are your exact testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck? Provide error stacktrace. 4. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: you're resetting `all` over and over again... Why not just scroll until you know you're done scrolling, and then make one call to set `all = driver.findElements(By.className("torpedo"));` after your loop? This might resolve an issue with a scroll happening one last time before you set your elements. It's hard to say for sure since I don't see what your `isContinue` is doing or any other part of your loop logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you keeps on resetting your list for every iteration of the loop. We can initiate the List outside the loop and keep om adding elements to the list inside the loop. The code should look something like this.

```
List<WebElement> all = null;
outer: while (isContinue) 
{    
     all.addAll(driver.findElements(By.className("torpedo")));
     /* do screen scrolling*/
}
```

You can also use a set instead of list if you get duplicate elements in the list.

```
Set<WebElement> all = null;
outer: while (isContinue) 
{    
     all.addAll(driver.findElements(By.className("torpedo")));
     /* do screen scrolling*/
}
```